# Adding anonymous array to property. Not possible?

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

I came across a property of the type String array during my work and decided to be smart about it and add an anonymous array of values to it, since I didn't need an array of values I was only going to use once sticking around. To my surprise though, it's not possible?

```
class Foo
{
    public String[] bar { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   String[] arr = { "val1", "val2", "val3" };
   foo.bar = arr;
   foreach (String bar in foo.bar)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(bar);
    }
 }
```

Not surprisingly outputs:
"val1"
"val2"
"val3"

But!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar = {"val1", "val2", "val3"};
}
```

Throws all kinds of nasty compiler errors.

Googled turned up short of an answer, so I'm turning to SO. Why is this not possible?

Comment: In what way is this "anonymous"? It's not using anonymous types, or anonymous methods... nothing in this code corresponds to any use of an "anonymous" term in C#, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't told it that you want an array; in your original line:

```
String[] arr = { "val1", "val2", "val3" };
```

it has enough information to understand what you want, but *outside of* such declarations with initializers more is needed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar = new[]{"val1", "val2", "val3"};
}
```

or (being much more specific, but functionally identical):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar = new string[3]{"val1", "val2", "val3"};
}
```

I'd say the first is preferable; less to get wrong ;p

As Jon notes; if you want to be *even less verbose* you can use an *object initializer*:

```
static void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo { bar = new[] {"val1", "val2", "val3"} };
}
```

Comment: You might want to mention the option of an object initializer, too.